# Java Card Accessing Objects over Shareable Interface

Tags: javacard

I am trying to access objects over a Shareable Interface in a Java Card between two applets.

The Server Applet codes:

```
package Wallet;

public class Wallet extends Applet implements IShareable {

    public static byte[] buf1 = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short) 258, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);

    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
        new Wallet();
    }

    protected Wallet() {
        register();
    }

    public Shareable getShareableInterfaceObject(AID clientAID, byte parameter) {
        return this;
    }

    public short getArray(byte[] buf, short off, short len) {
        Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(testArray, (short)0, buf, off, (short) 5);
        Util.arrayFillNonAtomic(buf1, (short) 0, (short) buf1.length, (byte) 0xAA); // <---- This is causing SecurityException
        return len;
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu) { ...... }

}
```

The Interface:

```
package Wallet;

import javacard.framework.*;

public interface IShareable extends Shareable {

    public short getArray(byte[] array, short off, short len);

}
```

The Client Applet codes:

```
package Test222;

import Wallet.IShareable;
import javacard.framework.*;

public class Test222 extends Applet {

    public AID appID = new AID(
            new byte[]{
                (byte) 0x54, (byte) 0x54, (byte) 0x54, (byte) 0x54, (byte) 0x54, (byte) 0x00
            },
            (short) 0,
            (byte) 6);
    public IShareable shared = null;
    public short[] sb1 = JCSystem.makeTransientShortArray((short) 1, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);

    /**
     * Installs this applet.
     *
     * @param bArray
     * the array containing installation parameters
     * @param bOffset
     * the starting offset in bArray
     * @param bLength
     * the length in bytes of the parameter data in bArray
     */
    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
        new Test222();
    }

    /**
     * Only this class's install method should create the applet object.
     */
    protected Test222() {
        register();
    }

    /**
     * Processes an incoming APDU.
     *
     * @see APDU
     * @param apdu
     * the incoming APDU
     */
    public void process(APDU apdu) {
        if (selectingApplet()) {
            return;
        }

        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();

        if ((buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] == (byte) 0xB0) && (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS] == (byte) 0x10)) {
            try {
                shared = (IShareable) JCSystem.getAppletShareableInterfaceObject(appAID, (byte) 0);
                if (shared != null) {
                    sb1[0] = shared.getArray(buffer, (short) 0, (short) 5);
                    apdu.setOutgoing();
                    apdu.setOutgoingLength(sb1[0]);
                    apdu.sendBytesLong(buffer, (short) 0, sb1[0]);
                } else {
                    ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_APPLET_SELECT_FAILED);
                }
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_DATA_INVALID);
            }
        } else {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_COMMAND_NOT_ALLOWED);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting SecurityException from the Server Applet side whenever I select the Client applet to call the Server Applet's `getArray` interface method. I traced it down to the Server side's `Util.arrayFillNonAtomic()` method when it accesses `buf1`. How do I get the `Util.arrayFillNonAtomic()` to execute as I am interested in copying the filled `buf1` to the `getArray`'s `buf` on a later portion of the code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am getting SecurityException from the Server Applet side

The `SecurityException` is thrown due to the invalid object access (`buf1`) by the calling context (server applet) or active context. This is according to the object access rules enforced by the firewall defined in JCRE specification.
https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/JCCRE/JCCRE.pdf

You can read the JCRE specification for the concept of context switching during the implementation of shareable interface objects.

In general, an object can only be accessed by its owning context, that is, when the owning context is the
currently active context. The firewall prevents an object from being accessed by another applet in a
different context. In implementation terms, each time an object is accessed, the object's owner context (calling applet) is compared to
the currently active context (called applet). If these do not match, the access is not performed and a `SecurityException` is thrown.

Particularly in your case,

Transient objects of `CLEAR_ON_DESELECT` type can only be created or accessed when the currently
**active context** is the **context of the currently selected applet**. Which is not the case here, because active context is **context of server applet** and currently selected applet is **client applet**.

However, you can change `buf1` to transient array of type `CLEAR_ON_RESET` because they behave like persistent objects in the sense that they can be
accessed when the **currently active context** (client applet) is the **object's owning context** (client applet).